# How can I use javascript to "click" a button that has no id or name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is relevant code

```
<div class="call-to-action call-to-action-g1">

<input type="submit" value="Siguiente paso" class="submit">
```

I can not modify this HTML code . So all I have is this only .
The page also has many submit buttons so getelementbyqueryall won't work

Comment: `getelementbyqueryall` does not even exist ;) Anyways, only you know the complete HTML. You have to find selector which narrows down the selection as much as possible and then select the correct element, e.g. by index. E.g. if there is only one element that matches `.call-to-action input[type=submit]` then you already got it. If there are multiple and yours is the second one, get the second element from the set.

Comment: Query by type then filter by value?

Comment: relevant code
<div class="call-to-action call-to-action-g1">
    
        <input type="submit" value="Siguiente paso" class="submit">
    
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jquery Solution**

```
$('input[value="Siguiente paso"]').trigger('click');
```

**Javascript Solution**

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[value="Siguiente paso"]').click();
```

**For Older Browsers**

```
function getInputsByValue(value)
{
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var results = [];
    for(var x=0;x<allInputs.length;x++)
        if(allInputs[x].value == value)
            results.push(allInputs[x]);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this uses jquery to fetch the input by value and then triggers the click event on it. It should work unless you have two submit button with the same value. If so then Royi solution will work.

Comment: @pravinkottawar Yes, Pure js solution added.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this :

`$("div.call-to-action.call-to-action-g1 > input[type='submit'].submit[value='Siguiente paso']").on('click',function (){...});`

(this is the specific I could find according to your code)

Comment: sorry this is not specific i need only click function not onclick and if possible pure javascript is needed

Comment: @pravinkottawar Huh ???? click _is_ a handler for _onclick_. and if you don't need jQuery then why you tag your question with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of, without knowing the index of the item, would be to use getElementsByClassName, and then loop through them all comparing the value. If you have two buttons with the same value, pretty sure you're out of options.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the container elements to reduce the scope of the search

```
$('.call-to-action-g1 input.submit')....
```

if you have multiple submit within the container then use the attribute selector along with `value` as shown by @Royi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using class :

```
$('.submit').click();
```

or

```
$('.submit').trigger( "click" );
```

Answer (score 0):

[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/55UUf/)

```
$('input.submit').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value) == 'Siguiente paso';
}).click(function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

---

to click

```
$('input.submit').filter(function () {
    return $.trim(this.value) == 'Siguiente paso';
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/Ud6Tw/)
You can still capture an event using the type !!

```
$('input').on("click",function(){
// your code here
});
```

if you want to refine it even more then you can get the value of clicked element using `this.value`
and have your code there

```
$('input').on("click",function(){
alert("Button clicked");
    if(this.value=="Siguiente paso"){
    alert("Siguiente paso clicked");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many selectors in jquery, not only by id or name.
Like this:

```
$('.submit').click();
```

also you can see more about the jquery Selector:http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

Try this pure-javascript solution:

```
document.querySelector(".call-to-action .submit").onclick = function() { 
  alert('bla bla'); 
}
```

Comment: can u modify it with just click i don't need onclick i can not change ui code. there are many submit buttons so ru sure it will work ???

Comment: Yes. This should work. The query selector will target the submit button in all divs to which `call-to-action` class is applied.

Comment: It is not working in 1st attempt when i re run it its working

Comment: Possibly the script is executing before the DOM has created the elements. Hence, it is not working on 1st attempt. You can try 2 things: 1. Try placing this script at the bottom of the page or place it in a function called on `body.onload`.